# How to use variables in different less files?

Tags: less

Let's say I separate a less files into many less files to be easy to organize.
Here is my repository:

```
/reset.less
/variables.less
/mixins.less
/main.less
/styles.less
```

The styles.less is just importing the other files:

```
@import "reset.less";
@import "mixins.less";
@import "variables.less";
@import "main.less";
```

However, when I add some codes into main.less and use the @line-color which is defined in the variables.less. It shows Name `Error: variable @line-color is undefined` and I cannot compile it- I use PHPStorm with less plugin.

Could you pleas suggest me?

Comment: Does it compile with `less.js` or another LESS compiler?

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 I use [intellij-lessc-plugin](https://github.com/acdvorak/intellij-lessc-plugin), which belongs to PHPStorm, to compile it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to import your variables.less to all files which use your variables.

**Edit:**

You have to compile only your style.less. You cannot compile the main.less because it doesn't know the variables.less but you don't want a main.CSS anyway, do you?
You should get the correct style.css which is (I guess) the only css file you'll need.

Comment: Thanks for you response. It would work if I import the variables.less to all files. However, I see many big project, [Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) for example, they do it without import their variables.less to all files. In addition, let say I have 50 files. One day, I would like to change the variables.less to var.less. It will be disaster. Do you have another way.

Comment: I'm working on files other than style.less (since the latter is only used for compiling), so style.less is never being modified. As a result it won't compile automatically with every change I make (in another less file) either. The solution would be that if I modify a less file, that PHPstorm automatically compiles style.less instead of trying to do that with the file that was modified. Is there a way this can be configured please (I tried to above answer with no luck)?

Answer (score 1):

I could solve it by doing the following in PHPstorm:

- Open Preferences…
- In Tools > File Watchers > Less (configure)
- Check "*track only root files*"
- Change the "Output paths to refresh" to `../css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css` (added "*../css/*" in front - depending on what folder you'd like to write the css files into)
- *(At this point you may want to check if this already does the job to your liking. If it doesn't, carry on to the next step…)*
- In Other Settings > LESS Profiles > (Your profile) (configure)
- Define "LESS source directory": `/Users/macuser/htdocs/MySite/sites/all/themes/mytheme/less` (depending on which folder contains the .less files)
- Define "Include file by path": `/Users/macuser/htdocs/MySite/sites/all/themes/mytheme/less/style.less` (file name depending on which .less file compiles the other .less files)
- Add "CSS output directory" by selecting the folder you wish to write the (minified) CSS files
- Enable *Compress CSS output* if desired

**Notice:** If *Compress CSS output* is enabled, this means that the code will be compressed everytime you right-click a `.less`-file and hit "Compile to CSS". By default the output will not be compressed with every modification you make to the `.less`-file. If you do want to compress the CSS straight away,

- Install *less-plugin-clean-css* using the following command in
  Terminal: `sudo npm install -g less-plugin-clean-css`
- Next, go to Tools > File Watchers > Less (configure), and change the "Arguments" to `--clean-css --no-color $FileName$` (added "--clean-css" in front).
  Now it will compile your CSS automatically while you're coding. You'll no longer need to compile manually.

Comment: Uh, this question was about *less*, the CSS pre-processor.  I have no idea what you're talking about with this answer.  It sounds like some kind of graphical editing tool, but you don't even mention what it is!  Perhaps you should stick to SimpleText.

Comment: OP: "I use **PHPStorm** with less plugin."